# Understanding run time with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

I was wondering if someone could help me understand why the following two programs run at significantly different speeds (first one takes like 1/10 of a second, second one takes like 3 seconds).

```
def gaussian(x, h, m, c):
    return list(h * exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*c**2)))

x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1001)

for i in range(1000):
    gaussian(x, 50, 500, 10)
```

and

```
def gaussian2(x, h, m, c):
    def computer(x):
        return h * exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*c**2))
    y = []
    for val in x:
        y.append(computer(val))
return y

x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1001)

for i in range(1000):
    gaussian2(x, 50, 500, 10)
```

The only reason I'd need the second version is because it let me look at all the elements in the list so I can perform other operations with them (not illustrated in this example). But that isn't what I am asking -- I am asking why the second form is so much slower than the first.

Thanks!

Comment: because (assuming that the `exp` function was imported from numpy) the first function works with vectorized data (vectors / arrays / columns / etc.) and the second one works with scalar values. Most of vectorized operations in numpy are implemented using Cython and are __much__ faster compared to their scalar alternatives...

Comment: Is `exp` `np.exp` or `math.exp`?

Answer (score 1):

MaxU is right that the main reason is the vectorized math in numpy is faster than the scalar math in Python.  Its also important to remember however that looping over a numpy array is a performance hit compared to looping over a Python list.  It doesn't show up as much as the math in this case, but there are other cases where it can be the major slowdown factor

```
import numpy as np
import math

def gaussian(x, h, m, c):
    return list(h * np.exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*c**2)))

def gaussian2(x, h, m, c):
    def computer(x):
        return h * math.exp(-(x-m)**2/(2*c**2))
    y = []
    for val in x:
        y.append(computer(val))
    return y

x = np.linspace(0, 1000, 1001)
x_list = x.tolist()

%timeit gaussian(x, 50, 500, 10)
%timeit gaussian2(x, 50, 500, 10)
%timeit gaussian2(x_list, 50, 500, 10)
```

yields:

```
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.97 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.35 ms per loop
```

so its clear the biggest bottleneck is the math, but there is a little slowdown from looping over the numpy array as compared with the list.